# Is it possible to restrict printing and downloading in google docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to make google docs read-only and to inhibit printing and downloading?

I don't want that users can download or make print or make any second copy of my shared data on google apps.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. If your users can see your data they can copy it. At the most basic level they can take a screenshot, even just point a camera at the monitor.